# How to put two divs on the same line with CSS in simple_form in rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, erb, simple-form

Putting two divs on the same line is an old question. But I can't find a solution when working with simple_form in rails. What I want to do is to display content and its label on the same line. The width of the label is 125px (`.left`) and the content is on the right (`.right`). The text in the label is aligned to the right and the text in content is aligned to the left.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="new_production" class="simple_form new_production" novalidate="novalidate" method="post" action="/projects/1/productions" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
        <input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8">
        <input type="hidden" value="2UQCUU+tKiKKtEiDtLLNeDrfBDoHTUmz5Sl9+JRVjALat3hFM=" name="authenticity_token">
    </div>
    <div class="left">Proj Name：</div>
    <div class="right">must have a name</div>
    <div class="input string required">
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.simple_form div.left {
  float: left;
  width: 125px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 2px 10px;
  display: inline;
}

.simple_form div.right {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 2px 10px;
  display: inline;
}
```

However, in the result, there is a linebreak, like so:

```
Proj Name：
must have a name
```

The erb code of the simple form is:

```
<div class="left">Proj Name：</div><div class="right"><%= @project.name %></div>
```

I don't want to use a table but CSS only to solve the issue.

Comment: The code shown works. Show us the code that does not work.

Comment: [Works here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vgqp9/1/) as it should be with `display:inline`, what's the problem ?

Comment: My guess is simple_form is generating an html wrapper. Can you show the browser generated html code?

Comment: The new HTML code you posted also displays fine with the CSS you have provided.

Comment: Did rake assets:precomple and restart rails server. It displays two lines. Is it not working because of the simple_form and rails?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your css is fine, but I think it's not applying on divs. Just write simple class name and then try.
You can check it at [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atinder123/h25Kb/).

```
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 125px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 2px 10px;
  display: inline;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 2px 10px;
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't float <strike>or set the width of</strike> an inline element. Remove `display: inline;` from both classes and your markup should present fine.

EDIT: You can set the width, but it will cause the element to be rendered as a block.

Answer (score 1):

why not use flexbox ? so wrap them into another div like that

```css
.flexContainer { 
   
  margin: 2px 10px;
  display: flex;
} 

.left {
  flex-basis : 30%;
}

.right {
  flex-basis : 30%;
}
```

```html
<form id="new_production" class="simple_form new_production" novalidate="novalidate" method="post" action="/projects/1/productions" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
        <input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8">
        <input type="hidden" value="2UQCUU+tKiKKtEiDtLLNeDrfBDoHTUmz5Sl9+JRVjALat3hFM=" name="authenticity_token">
    </div>
    <div class="flexContainer">
      <div class="left">Proj Name：</div>
      <div class="right">must have a name</div>
    </div>
    <div class="input string required"> </div>
 </form>
```

feel free to play with flex-basis percentage to get more customized space.